# How to tell the Rust compiler that you have handled "Value used here after move" case

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Here is my code for one of the leetcode problems:

```
    pub fn group_strings(strings: Vec<String>) -> Vec<Vec<String>> {
        let mut strings_iter = strings.into_iter();

        // Unwrap because the pblm guarantees that strings len >= 1
        let mut result = vec![vec![strings_iter.next().unwrap()]];

        let mut seq_found: bool = false;
        while let Some(input_string) = strings_iter.next() {
            // Is this string in seq with any of the strings in the result?
            for output_string_list in result.iter_mut() {
                if Solution::are_in_seq(&output_string_list[0], &input_string) {
                    // We are cloning because rust complains that we are using input_string
                    // after it is moved here, although seq_found flag ensures that we don't.
                    output_string_list.push(input_string);
                    seq_found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if !seq_found {
                result.push(vec![input_string]);
            }
            seq_found = false;            
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The compiler error that I get is:

```
Line 22, Char 34: use of moved value: `input_string` (solution.rs)
   |
9 |         while let Some(input_string) = strings_iter.next() {
   |                        ------------
   |                        |
   |                        this reinitialization might get skipped
   |                        move occurs because `input_string` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
15 |                     output_string_list.push(input_string);
   |                                             ------------ value moved here
...
22 |                 result.push(vec![input_string]);
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

I only push `input_string` if `seq_found`. But the compiler flags this as possible use after move. Whats the best way to tell the compiler that I handled this case? To get around this, I can do:

```
output_string_list.push(input_string.clone());
```

But this clone is an unnecessary and could potentially be an expensive operation.

Comment: Besides restructuring the code, you could simply put `input_string` into an `Option` before the inner loop, `.take()` it out of the `Option`-value to use it inside the inner loop, and check if the `Option` still has a value or is `None` after the loop. The bit in `Option` would simultaneously do the job that `seq_used` currently does.

Comment: Can you accept the other answer? It's more idiomatic than mine. I was wed too strongly to the existing loop structure.

Comment: I agree its more idiomatic but your answer explained the concept better. Hence I chose this as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by using control-flow structures (which the compiler understands) instead of the values of `bool`s (which the compiler doesn't understand). With a labeled loop, you can `continue` the loop, which the compiler understands prevents the rest of the loop body from executing, and similarly understands that if we don't `continue`, we never consumed `input_string`, as they occur in the same block.

```rust
pub fn group_strings(strings: Vec<String>) -> Vec<Vec<String>> {
    let mut strings_iter = strings.into_iter();

    // Unwrap because the pblm guarantees that strings len >= 1
    let mut result = vec![vec![strings_iter.next().unwrap()]];

    'find: while let Some(input_string) = strings_iter.next() {
        // Is this string in seq with any of the strings in the result?
        for output_string_list in result.iter_mut() {
            if Solution::are_in_seq(&output_string_list[0], &input_string) {
                output_string_list.push(input_string);
                continue 'find;
            }
        }

        // can only get here if we never continued above, 
        // so `input_string` was definitely not moved
        result.push(vec![input_string]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

(Incidentally, this code is also much shorter and has one fewer variable.)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `for`, which may confuse your control flow, you can use some iterator operations to first find a matching list and then move `input_string` depending on if a match was found or not:

```
pub fn group_strings(strings: Vec<String>) -> Vec<Vec<String>> {
    let mut strings_iter = strings.into_iter();

    // Unwrap because the pblm guarantees that strings len >= 1
    let mut result = vec![vec![strings_iter.next().unwrap()]];

    let mut seq_found: bool = false;
    while let Some(input_string) = strings_iter.next() {
        // Is this string in seq with any of the strings in the result?
        
        let maybe_output_string_list = result.iter_mut().find(|output_string_list| {
            Solution::are_in_seq(&output_string_list[0], &input_string)
        });
        
        if let Some(output_string_list) = maybe_output_string_list {
            output_string_list.push(input_string);
        } else {
            result.push(vec![input_string]);
        }       
    }

    result
}
```